# Метод дихотомии к нахождению частного от деления целых чисел

Tags: c++, алгоритм, деление

пусть даны два больших целых числа `A, B` длины соотвественно `n, и m` по основанию `BASE, BASE = 10^k, k >= 1`. Как найти быстро `q[i]` ую цифру частного от деления `a`(та часть числа A которое >= B) на `B` такую что `a <= B*q[i]`? Линейным перебором q[i] выходит очень медленно, понимаю что бинарным поиском находить будет быстрее, скажем если положить `l = 0, r = BASE` то `l <= q[i] < BASE` тоесть `q[i]` точно лежит в этом интервале, но что делать дальше ???

Comment: http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=210512&hl= = может, поможет

Comment: алгоритм где-то был у Кнута

Comment: общее соображение: количество разрядов частного равно либо `n-m`, либо `n-m+1`. не зависит от основания системы счисления.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это понятно, я прошу прощения, но имелось ввиду что q это i ая цифра всего частного Q, а она лежит от 0 до BASE тоесть всё таки зависит от основания. число а - это та очередная часть числа A которое мы на шаге алгоритмы делим на b. Так вот бинарный поиск для q именно здесь нужно применить но как ?

Comment: [вот это](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%B2_b-%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29) не поможет? **upd** кажется, про это уже подсказывали.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin почитаю.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле всё не так сложно. Вам проще всего вместо простого бинарного поиска воспользоваться поиском *нижней границы*: наименьшего индекса, для которого выполняется условие. Такой алгоритм приведён, например, [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Deferred_detection_of_equality).

Пусть вы уже знаете старшие цифры частного, и угадываете `i`-ую. Имея пробное частное `q`, вы должны умножить `q` на `b` и вычесть полученное число из `a` (пусть результат будет `r`). Если `r` отрицательно, то `b` слишком большое, и вам надо продолжать бинарный поиск в сторону уменьшения `b`. Остальные `b` можно считать, что подходят. Алгоритм даст вам наименьшее такое `b`, что вам как раз и нужно.

Вычисление исходит из того, что вы умеете умножать ваше многозначное число на однозначное (по базе `BASE`) `q`.

---

Вам на самом деле нужен алгоритм деления с многократной точностью. Он описан в [TAOCP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) под номером 4.3.1D. Этот алгоритм также базируется на умении *умножать* ваши многозначные числа на однозначные, и «угадывает» очередную цифру частного за максимум две попытки. Это должно быть скорее, чем двоичный поиск.

Comment: Я всё таки реализовал бин поиском нахождение частного, но видимо тот последний алгоритм с угадыванием по шустрее будет. Его тоже почитать надо будет.